# PCA reduction resulted in an elliptical form

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I have a dataset with 19 features (columns). I normalized them using sklearn.preprocessing.normalize then I used PCA to reduce them to 2 components for plotting purposes following the steps in this link:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html

What I saw is that my data points form a perfect ellipse shape as in the following picture:
[image: K-means clustering with PCA reduction]

I want to know if this has any special meaning for my data.

Comment: this is not a coding question,  you should consider moving it to [computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [data science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.  they'll probably be more help  :)

Comment: @Shtut sorry about that. I'll post it there

Comment: @Veltz sampled from real-world domain but I normalized them using sklearn.preprocessing.normalize

Comment: Sorry for removing my comment, I though you were moving :) I can't see the image, is it a full approximate ellipse (if so this is about the most common shape there is) or an empty ellipse?

Comment: I created another post here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25664/pca-reduction-resulted-in-an-elliptical-form

Comment: Either you did something wrong or you have a *very* strange dataset. What data are that?

Comment: @amoeba I normalized them using sklearn.preprocessing.normalize

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. What data are you working with?

Comment: It took me some time to understand that the black ellipsis is in fact the scatter plot of your points. Well, @amoeba is right, this is of course possible but in this case your data points are not random measures, they look totally deterministic

Comment: They are financial data in my company. Transactions

Comment: OK then this cannot be correct. Please post your code, otherwise I am afraid this is unanswerable.